# Find min max range of multiple variables the results in maximum PnL

Tags: python, java, algorithm, optimization, linear-programming

Given a table of N columns, all columns except last are variables and the last column is PnL (Profit and Loss). Each variable value is a whole number (no fractions, decimals) greater than or equals 0 and less than 20. PnL values can be greater than or less than zero.

Actual dataset may have upto 40 variables and 30,000 rows.

I'm trying to write a program to find minimum and maximum value for each variable such that the sum of matching PnL values derived from combination of all those minimum and maximum ranges results in the highest value.

Sample Data:
Large: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1afKF0mepBUWq0-inKIEOpKpzawBh9Z0Q/view?usp=sharing
Medium: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MGHdwBHYc0XVsup7I4bAJSHCl7V_J428/view?usp=sharing

Another example. A solution for below tiny table is:

```
(1 <= v1 <= 2) && (4 <= v2 <= 5); PnL Sum = 6 (3.5 + 2.5)

V1  V2  PnL
1   4   3.5
2   5   2.5
2   6   -11.0
```

I came up with [brute force approach](https://gist.github.com/amarsheriff/00427e74bcc578c1c13b0e7eaf171060), i.e. trying all possible combinations to find maximum PnL, but it takes too much time when more than 3 variables are involved.

Brute Force Approach (too slow for >3 variables):

```java
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/*
 * Brute Force Solution
 */
public class VariableOptimizer {

    double maxPnL = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    int[][] optimalMinMax = null;
    double[][] varMinMax = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /*
            Constraints:
            Vairables are whole Numbers (no fractions, decimals) and range between 0 to 19;
            i.e. variable v >= 0 and <= 19
         */
        double[][] data = {
              //{v1, v2, v3, PnL}
                {7, 8, 12, 100.50},
                {6, 9, 14, -200.10},
                {5, 10, 13, 150.25},
                {8, 11, 15, -510.35},
        };

        //data = loadCsv("./Optimize-MinMax.csv"); //or load data from file

        VariableOptimizer variableOptimizer = new VariableOptimizer();

        variableOptimizer.findOptimalMinMax(data, 0, null);

        System.out.println("maxPnL: " + variableOptimizer.maxPnL);

        for (int i = 0; i < variableOptimizer.optimalMinMax.length; i++){
            System.out.println("v" +i + " Min: " + variableOptimizer.optimalMinMax[i][0] + ", Max: " + variableOptimizer.optimalMinMax[i][1]);
        }
    }

    public void findOptimalMinMax(double[][] data, int varIdx, int[][] varMinMaxConditions){

        int noOfVars = data[0].length-1;

        if (varMinMaxConditions == null) {
            varMinMaxConditions = new int[noOfVars][2];
        }

        if (varIdx == noOfVars) {

            double pnl = calculatePnl(data, varMinMaxConditions);

            if (pnl >= maxPnL) {
                maxPnL = pnl;
                optimalMinMax = java.util.Arrays.stream(varMinMaxConditions)
                        .map(a ->  java.util.Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length))
                        .toArray(int[][]::new);
            }
            return;
        }

        double[][] varMinMax = getVarMinMax(data);
        int varMin = (int)varMinMax[varIdx][0];
        int varMax = (int)varMinMax[varIdx][1];

        for (int i = varMin; i <= varMax; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j <= varMax; j++ ) {

                varMinMaxConditions[varIdx][0] = i;
                varMinMaxConditions[varIdx][1] = j;

                findOptimalMinMax(data, varIdx + 1, varMinMaxConditions);
            }
        }
    }

    public static double calculatePnl(double[][] data, int[][] varMinMaxConditions){

        double pnl = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            double[] row = data[i];
            double rowPnl = row[row.length-1];

            boolean includeRow = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < varMinMaxConditions.length; j++){

                double varMin = varMinMaxConditions[j][0];
                double varMax = varMinMaxConditions[j][1];

                if (varMin > row[j] || row[j] > varMax){
                    includeRow = false;
                }
            }

            if (includeRow) {
                pnl += rowPnl;
            }
        }

        return pnl;
    }

    public double[][] getVarMinMax(double[][] data){

        if (varMinMax == null) {
            int noOfVars = data[0].length - 1;

            varMinMax = new double[noOfVars][2];

            for (int rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < data.length; rowIdx++) {
                for (int varIdx = 0; varIdx < noOfVars; varIdx++) {
                    if (rowIdx > 0) {
                        varMinMax[varIdx][0] = Math.min(data[rowIdx][varIdx], varMinMax[varIdx][0]);
                        varMinMax[varIdx][1] = (int)Math.max(data[rowIdx][varIdx], varMinMax[varIdx][1]);
                    } else {
                        varMinMax[varIdx][0] = data[rowIdx][varIdx];
                        varMinMax[varIdx][1] = data[rowIdx][varIdx];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return varMinMax;
    }

    public static double[][] loadCsv(String file){
        List<double[]> rows = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Files.lines(Paths.get(file)).forEach(s -> {
                if (!java.lang.Character.isDigit(s.charAt(0))) return;
                String[] line = s.split(",");
                double[] row = Arrays.stream(line)
                        .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
                        .toArray();
                rows.add(row);
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        double[][] result = new double[rows.size()][];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {
            result[i] = rows.get(i);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Can someone please help solve this?

Comment: How do each of the columns correspond to the last one?

Comment: Still not very sure how you are calculating PnL.
But this seems to me like a linear regression problem.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson the PnL values are from actual trades and variable values are captured at the entry time of those trades. so PnL values are not calculated using the variables.

Comment: Are you saying that you're trying to find mix/max of pnl dynamically and it's too slow on the machine you are running on? Please share that relevant code if so.

Comment: Have you actually run your algorithm on your sample data? What outputs do you expect to get for it?

Comment: I've written a local LP implementation, and for your sample data the optimal thing to do for subsets of your data above the first ~10 rows is to select nothing. Are the data randomly generated? If so this is expected and your sample data need to be more realistic.

Comment: Don't link a gist; you need to embed your code

Comment: varMinMaxConditions seems arbitrary - why are you looping to create this, and what is the significance of 19?

Comment: @ryanwebjackson varMinMaxConditions has min/max conditions of all vars to check if row PnL has to be included or not. each var value is: 0 <= var && var <= 19

Comment: Your brute-force approach does not show its output. When I run the example data it processes, the optimal strategy is to select only one row, so it's not a very good illustration, and I expect that for larger-scale problems (which it seems your brute-force solution has not attempted at all), the original problem remains: for the construction of your problem, unless the `v` dimensions are highly correlated, the best strategy will be to select nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Linear programming is a viable approach, made a little tricky by the fact that your range constraints need to fit into two cases:

- When a row needs to be included, it needs to fit within the range when the assignment boolean is high (or relaxed constraints when it's low) - easy, but...
- When a row needs to be *excluded*, it needs to be *outside* of the range. This is easier said than done. Enforcing a range exclusion, as [Cornell University](https://optimization.cbe.cornell.edu/index.php?title=Optimization_with_absolute_values#Form_when_.7F.27.22.60UNIQ--postMath-00000013-QINU.60.22.27.7F) writes, is non-convex and requires a new binary variable for each element.

This approach is able to run pretty quickly on your sample of 150 rows. However, those sample data are (I'm guessing) randomly generated, and as such are uniquely terrible for this algorithm: for a perfectly uniform distribution of your input variables, as the number of rows increases, the optimal strategy will always be to select nothing.

Running on this toy example instead:

```
v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,PnL
1,3,3,3,3,-500
2,4,4,4,4,100
2,4,5,4,5,100
4,7,7,7,7,100
5,8,8,8,8,-500
6,9,9,9,9,150
```

is much more illustrative of what a successful algorithm should do, and indeed, it produces a sensible choice:

```
PnL total: 300.00
Assigned rows: 3/6
Bounds:
    lower  upper
v1    1.5    4.0
v2    3.5    7.0
v3    3.5    7.0
v4    3.5    7.0
v5    3.5    7.0
```

### Implementation

Shown in Python for brevity.

```py
import pandas as pd
import pulp


def make_col_vars(v_name: str) -> pd.Series:
    lower = pulp.LpVariable(name='lower_' + v_name, lowBound=0, upBound=19)
    upper = pulp.LpVariable(name='upper_' + v_name, lowBound=0, upBound=19)
    prob.addConstraint(name='interval_' + v_name, constraint=lower <= upper)
    return pd.Series(data=(lower, upper), index=('lower', 'upper'))


def make_row_vars(row: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    assign = pulp.LpVariable(name=f'asn_{row.idx:03.0f}', cat=pulp.LpBinary)

    for v_name, v in row[:-2].iteritems():
        v_bounds = bounds.loc[v_name]
        suffix = f'_{v_name}_{row.idx:03.0f}'

        # If assign, then v_bounds.lower <= v <= v_bounds.upper
        prob.addConstraint(name='lower_in' + suffix, constraint=v >= v_bounds.lower - 25*(1 - assign))
        prob.addConstraint(name='upper_in' + suffix, constraint=v <= v_bounds.upper + 25*(1 - assign))

        # otherwise v must be outside of those bounds
        # v <= lower-1 || upper+1 <= v

        is_upper = pulp.LpVariable(name='is_upper' + suffix, cat=pulp.LpBinary)
        # enforce if is_upper && !assigned
        prob.addConstraint(name='upper_out' + suffix, constraint=v >= v_bounds.upper+0.5 - 25*(assign - is_upper + 1))
        # enforce if !is_upper && !assigned
        prob.addConstraint(name='lower_out' + suffix, constraint=v <= v_bounds.lower-0.5 + 25*(assign + is_upper))

    return pd.Series((assign,))


df = pd.read_csv('Optimize-MinMax.csv')
prob = pulp.LpProblem(name='profit_loss', sense=pulp.LpMaximize)
bounds = df.columns[:-1].to_series().apply(make_col_vars)
df['idx'] = df.index
df['assign'] = df.apply(make_row_vars, axis=1)

prob.objective = pulp.lpDot(df.PnL, df['assign'])

print(prob)
prob.solve()
assert prob.status == pulp.const.LpStatusOptimal

print(f'PnL total: {prob.objective.value():.2f}')
n_assigned = df["assign"].apply(pulp.LpVariable.value).sum()
print(f'Assigned rows: {n_assigned:.0f}/{len(df)}')
print('Bounds:')
print(bounds.applymap(pulp.LpVariable.value))
```

### Output

```
profit_loss:
MAXIMIZE
-500*asn_000 + 100*asn_001 + 100*asn_002 + 100*asn_003 + -500*asn_004 + 150*asn_005 + 0
SUBJECT TO
interval_v1: lower_v1 - upper_v1 <= 0

interval_v2: lower_v2 - upper_v2 <= 0

interval_v3: lower_v3 - upper_v3 <= 0

interval_v4: lower_v4 - upper_v4 <= 0

interval_v5: lower_v5 - upper_v5 <= 0

lower_in_v1_000: 25 asn_000 + lower_v1 <= 26

upper_in_v1_000: - 25 asn_000 + upper_v1 >= -24

upper_out_v1_000: - 25 asn_000 + 25 is_upper_v1_000 + upper_v1 <= 25.5

lower_out_v1_000: 25 asn_000 + 25 is_upper_v1_000 + lower_v1 >= 1.5

lower_in_v2_000: 25 asn_000 + lower_v2 <= 28

upper_in_v2_000: - 25 asn_000 + upper_v2 >= -22

upper_out_v2_000: - 25 asn_000 + 25 is_upper_v2_000 + upper_v2 <= 27.5

lower_out_v2_000: 25 asn_000 + 25 is_upper_v2_000 + lower_v2 >= 3.5

lower_in_v3_000: 25 asn_000 + lower_v3 <= 28

upper_in_v3_000: - 25 asn_000 + upper_v3 >= -22

upper_out_v3_000: - 25 asn_000 + 25 is_upper_v3_000 + upper_v3 <= 27.5

lower_out_v3_000: 25 asn_000 + 25 is_upper_v3_000 + lower_v3 >= 3.5

lower_in_v4_000: 25 asn_000 + lower_v4 <= 28

upper_in_v4_000: - 25 asn_000 + upper_v4 >= -22

upper_out_v4_000: - 25 asn_000 + 25 is_upper_v4_000 + upper_v4 <= 27.5

lower_out_v4_000: 25 asn_000 + 25 is_upper_v4_000 + lower_v4 >= 3.5

lower_in_v5_000: 25 asn_000 + lower_v5 <= 28

upper_in_v5_000: - 25 asn_000 + upper_v5 >= -22

upper_out_v5_000: - 25 asn_000 + 25 is_upper_v5_000 + upper_v5 <= 27.5

lower_out_v5_000: 25 asn_000 + 25 is_upper_v5_000 + lower_v5 >= 3.5

lower_in_v1_001: 25 asn_001 + lower_v1 <= 27

upper_in_v1_001: - 25 asn_001 + upper_v1 >= -23

upper_out_v1_001: - 25 asn_001 + 25 is_upper_v1_001 + upper_v1 <= 26.5

lower_out_v1_001: 25 asn_001 + 25 is_upper_v1_001 + lower_v1 >= 2.5

lower_in_v2_001: 25 asn_001 + lower_v2 <= 29

upper_in_v2_001: - 25 asn_001 + upper_v2 >= -21

upper_out_v2_001: - 25 asn_001 + 25 is_upper_v2_001 + upper_v2 <= 28.5

lower_out_v2_001: 25 asn_001 + 25 is_upper_v2_001 + lower_v2 >= 4.5

lower_in_v3_001: 25 asn_001 + lower_v3 <= 29

upper_in_v3_001: - 25 asn_001 + upper_v3 >= -21

upper_out_v3_001: - 25 asn_001 + 25 is_upper_v3_001 + upper_v3 <= 28.5

lower_out_v3_001: 25 asn_001 + 25 is_upper_v3_001 + lower_v3 >= 4.5

lower_in_v4_001: 25 asn_001 + lower_v4 <= 29

upper_in_v4_001: - 25 asn_001 + upper_v4 >= -21

upper_out_v4_001: - 25 asn_001 + 25 is_upper_v4_001 + upper_v4 <= 28.5

lower_out_v4_001: 25 asn_001 + 25 is_upper_v4_001 + lower_v4 >= 4.5

lower_in_v5_001: 25 asn_001 + lower_v5 <= 29

upper_in_v5_001: - 25 asn_001 + upper_v5 >= -21

upper_out_v5_001: - 25 asn_001 + 25 is_upper_v5_001 + upper_v5 <= 28.5

lower_out_v5_001: 25 asn_001 + 25 is_upper_v5_001 + lower_v5 >= 4.5

lower_in_v1_002: 25 asn_002 + lower_v1 <= 27

upper_in_v1_002: - 25 asn_002 + upper_v1 >= -23

upper_out_v1_002: - 25 asn_002 + 25 is_upper_v1_002 + upper_v1 <= 26.5

lower_out_v1_002: 25 asn_002 + 25 is_upper_v1_002 + lower_v1 >= 2.5

lower_in_v2_002: 25 asn_002 + lower_v2 <= 29

upper_in_v2_002: - 25 asn_002 + upper_v2 >= -21

upper_out_v2_002: - 25 asn_002 + 25 is_upper_v2_002 + upper_v2 <= 28.5

lower_out_v2_002: 25 asn_002 + 25 is_upper_v2_002 + lower_v2 >= 4.5

lower_in_v3_002: 25 asn_002 + lower_v3 <= 30

upper_in_v3_002: - 25 asn_002 + upper_v3 >= -20

upper_out_v3_002: - 25 asn_002 + 25 is_upper_v3_002 + upper_v3 <= 29.5

lower_out_v3_002: 25 asn_002 + 25 is_upper_v3_002 + lower_v3 >= 5.5

lower_in_v4_002: 25 asn_002 + lower_v4 <= 29

upper_in_v4_002: - 25 asn_002 + upper_v4 >= -21

upper_out_v4_002: - 25 asn_002 + 25 is_upper_v4_002 + upper_v4 <= 28.5

lower_out_v4_002: 25 asn_002 + 25 is_upper_v4_002 + lower_v4 >= 4.5

lower_in_v5_002: 25 asn_002 + lower_v5 <= 30

upper_in_v5_002: - 25 asn_002 + upper_v5 >= -20

upper_out_v5_002: - 25 asn_002 + 25 is_upper_v5_002 + upper_v5 <= 29.5

lower_out_v5_002: 25 asn_002 + 25 is_upper_v5_002 + lower_v5 >= 5.5

lower_in_v1_003: 25 asn_003 + lower_v1 <= 29

upper_in_v1_003: - 25 asn_003 + upper_v1 >= -21

upper_out_v1_003: - 25 asn_003 + 25 is_upper_v1_003 + upper_v1 <= 28.5

lower_out_v1_003: 25 asn_003 + 25 is_upper_v1_003 + lower_v1 >= 4.5

lower_in_v2_003: 25 asn_003 + lower_v2 <= 32

upper_in_v2_003: - 25 asn_003 + upper_v2 >= -18

upper_out_v2_003: - 25 asn_003 + 25 is_upper_v2_003 + upper_v2 <= 31.5

lower_out_v2_003: 25 asn_003 + 25 is_upper_v2_003 + lower_v2 >= 7.5

lower_in_v3_003: 25 asn_003 + lower_v3 <= 32

upper_in_v3_003: - 25 asn_003 + upper_v3 >= -18

upper_out_v3_003: - 25 asn_003 + 25 is_upper_v3_003 + upper_v3 <= 31.5

lower_out_v3_003: 25 asn_003 + 25 is_upper_v3_003 + lower_v3 >= 7.5

lower_in_v4_003: 25 asn_003 + lower_v4 <= 32

upper_in_v4_003: - 25 asn_003 + upper_v4 >= -18

upper_out_v4_003: - 25 asn_003 + 25 is_upper_v4_003 + upper_v4 <= 31.5

lower_out_v4_003: 25 asn_003 + 25 is_upper_v4_003 + lower_v4 >= 7.5

lower_in_v5_003: 25 asn_003 + lower_v5 <= 32

upper_in_v5_003: - 25 asn_003 + upper_v5 >= -18

upper_out_v5_003: - 25 asn_003 + 25 is_upper_v5_003 + upper_v5 <= 31.5

lower_out_v5_003: 25 asn_003 + 25 is_upper_v5_003 + lower_v5 >= 7.5

lower_in_v1_004: 25 asn_004 + lower_v1 <= 30

upper_in_v1_004: - 25 asn_004 + upper_v1 >= -20

upper_out_v1_004: - 25 asn_004 + 25 is_upper_v1_004 + upper_v1 <= 29.5

lower_out_v1_004: 25 asn_004 + 25 is_upper_v1_004 + lower_v1 >= 5.5

lower_in_v2_004: 25 asn_004 + lower_v2 <= 33

upper_in_v2_004: - 25 asn_004 + upper_v2 >= -17

upper_out_v2_004: - 25 asn_004 + 25 is_upper_v2_004 + upper_v2 <= 32.5

lower_out_v2_004: 25 asn_004 + 25 is_upper_v2_004 + lower_v2 >= 8.5

lower_in_v3_004: 25 asn_004 + lower_v3 <= 33

upper_in_v3_004: - 25 asn_004 + upper_v3 >= -17

upper_out_v3_004: - 25 asn_004 + 25 is_upper_v3_004 + upper_v3 <= 32.5

lower_out_v3_004: 25 asn_004 + 25 is_upper_v3_004 + lower_v3 >= 8.5

lower_in_v4_004: 25 asn_004 + lower_v4 <= 33

upper_in_v4_004: - 25 asn_004 + upper_v4 >= -17

upper_out_v4_004: - 25 asn_004 + 25 is_upper_v4_004 + upper_v4 <= 32.5

lower_out_v4_004: 25 asn_004 + 25 is_upper_v4_004 + lower_v4 >= 8.5

lower_in_v5_004: 25 asn_004 + lower_v5 <= 33

upper_in_v5_004: - 25 asn_004 + upper_v5 >= -17

upper_out_v5_004: - 25 asn_004 + 25 is_upper_v5_004 + upper_v5 <= 32.5

lower_out_v5_004: 25 asn_004 + 25 is_upper_v5_004 + lower_v5 >= 8.5

lower_in_v1_005: 25 asn_005 + lower_v1 <= 31

upper_in_v1_005: - 25 asn_005 + upper_v1 >= -19

upper_out_v1_005: - 25 asn_005 + 25 is_upper_v1_005 + upper_v1 <= 30.5

lower_out_v1_005: 25 asn_005 + 25 is_upper_v1_005 + lower_v1 >= 6.5

lower_in_v2_005: 25 asn_005 + lower_v2 <= 34

upper_in_v2_005: - 25 asn_005 + upper_v2 >= -16

upper_out_v2_005: - 25 asn_005 + 25 is_upper_v2_005 + upper_v2 <= 33.5

lower_out_v2_005: 25 asn_005 + 25 is_upper_v2_005 + lower_v2 >= 9.5

lower_in_v3_005: 25 asn_005 + lower_v3 <= 34

upper_in_v3_005: - 25 asn_005 + upper_v3 >= -16

upper_out_v3_005: - 25 asn_005 + 25 is_upper_v3_005 + upper_v3 <= 33.5

lower_out_v3_005: 25 asn_005 + 25 is_upper_v3_005 + lower_v3 >= 9.5

lower_in_v4_005: 25 asn_005 + lower_v4 <= 34

upper_in_v4_005: - 25 asn_005 + upper_v4 >= -16

upper_out_v4_005: - 25 asn_005 + 25 is_upper_v4_005 + upper_v4 <= 33.5

lower_out_v4_005: 25 asn_005 + 25 is_upper_v4_005 + lower_v4 >= 9.5

lower_in_v5_005: 25 asn_005 + lower_v5 <= 34

upper_in_v5_005: - 25 asn_005 + upper_v5 >= -16

upper_out_v5_005: - 25 asn_005 + 25 is_upper_v5_005 + upper_v5 <= 33.5

lower_out_v5_005: 25 asn_005 + 25 is_upper_v5_005 + lower_v5 >= 9.5

VARIABLES
0 <= asn_000 <= 1 Integer
0 <= asn_001 <= 1 Integer
0 <= asn_002 <= 1 Integer
0 <= asn_003 <= 1 Integer
0 <= asn_004 <= 1 Integer
0 <= asn_005 <= 1 Integer
0 <= is_upper_v1_000 <= 1 Integer
0 <= is_upper_v1_001 <= 1 Integer
0 <= is_upper_v1_002 <= 1 Integer
0 <= is_upper_v1_003 <= 1 Integer
0 <= is_upper_v1_004 <= 1 Integer
0 <= is_upper_v1_005 <= 1 Integer
0 <= is_upper_v2_000 <= 1 Integer
0 <= is_upper_v2_001 <= 1 Integer
0 <= is_upper_v2_002 <= 1 Integer
0 <= is_upper_v2_003 <= 1 Integer
0 <= is_upper_v2_004 <= 1 Integer
0 <= is_upper_v2_005 <= 1 Integer
0 <= is_upper_v3_000 <= 1 Integer
0 <= is_upper_v3_001 <= 1 Integer
0 <= is_upper_v3_002 <= 1 Integer
0 <= is_upper_v3_003 <= 1 Integer
0 <= is_upper_v3_004 <= 1 Integer
0 <= is_upper_v3_005 <= 1 Integer
0 <= is_upper_v4_000 <= 1 Integer
0 <= is_upper_v4_001 <= 1 Integer
0 <= is_upper_v4_002 <= 1 Integer
0 <= is_upper_v4_003 <= 1 Integer
0 <= is_upper_v4_004 <= 1 Integer
0 <= is_upper_v4_005 <= 1 Integer
0 <= is_upper_v5_000 <= 1 Integer
0 <= is_upper_v5_001 <= 1 Integer
0 <= is_upper_v5_002 <= 1 Integer
0 <= is_upper_v5_003 <= 1 Integer
0 <= is_upper_v5_004 <= 1 Integer
0 <= is_upper_v5_005 <= 1 Integer
lower_v1 <= 19 Continuous
lower_v2 <= 19 Continuous
lower_v3 <= 19 Continuous
lower_v4 <= 19 Continuous
lower_v5 <= 19 Continuous
upper_v1 <= 19 Continuous
upper_v2 <= 19 Continuous
upper_v3 <= 19 Continuous
upper_v4 <= 19 Continuous
upper_v5 <= 19 Continuous

Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver 
Version: 2.10.3 
Build Date: Dec 15 2019 

command line - .venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pulp/solverdir/cbc/linux/64/cbc /tmp/a0190fc1d26e4a6483cbe40c45b4eb2f-pulp.mps max timeMode elapsed branch printingOptions all solution /tmp/a0190fc1d26e4a6483cbe40c45b4eb2f-pulp.sol (default strategy 1)
At line 2 NAME          MODEL
At line 3 ROWS
At line 130 COLUMNS
At line 519 RHS
At line 645 BOUNDS
At line 692 ENDATA
Problem MODEL has 125 rows, 46 columns and 310 elements
Coin0008I MODEL read with 0 errors
Option for timeMode changed from cpu to elapsed
Continuous objective value is 450 - 0.00 seconds
Cgl0003I 0 fixed, 0 tightened bounds, 60 strengthened rows, 0 substitutions
Cgl0003I 0 fixed, 0 tightened bounds, 15 strengthened rows, 0 substitutions
Cgl0003I 0 fixed, 0 tightened bounds, 10 strengthened rows, 0 substitutions
Cgl0004I processed model has 125 rows, 46 columns (36 integer (36 of which binary)) and 385 elements
Cutoff increment increased from 1e-05 to 49.9999
Cbc0038I Initial state - 10 integers unsatisfied sum - 2.62534
Cbc0038I Pass   1: suminf.    0.51766 (6) obj. -262.65 iterations 40
Cbc0038I Pass   2: suminf.    0.37920 (2) obj. 810.4 iterations 24
Cbc0038I Pass   3: suminf.    0.55711 (3) obj. 119.936 iterations 5
Cbc0038I Pass   4: suminf.    0.24000 (2) obj. 269 iterations 10
Cbc0038I Pass   5: suminf.    0.51356 (2) obj. 119.936 iterations 7
Cbc0038I Pass   6: suminf.    0.89604 (5) obj. 141.923 iterations 14
Cbc0038I Pass   7: suminf.    0.59491 (5) obj. 670.688 iterations 15
Cbc0038I Pass   8: suminf.    0.92668 (5) obj. 51.2876 iterations 25
Cbc0038I Pass   9: suminf.    0.92668 (5) obj. 51.2876 iterations 7
Cbc0038I Pass  10: suminf.    0.59689 (6) obj. 667.219 iterations 33
Cbc0038I Pass  11: suminf.    0.92668 (5) obj. 51.2876 iterations 29
Cbc0038I Pass  12: suminf.    0.48428 (4) obj. 662.897 iterations 20
Cbc0038I Pass  13: suminf.    0.95405 (6) obj. 119.888 iterations 20
Cbc0038I Pass  14: suminf.    0.27012 (5) obj. 612.921 iterations 30
Cbc0038I Pass  15: suminf.    0.92255 (5) obj. 116.433 iterations 26
Cbc0038I Pass  16: suminf.    0.65069 (6) obj. 181.373 iterations 17
Cbc0038I Pass  17: suminf.    0.85917 (5) obj. 551.764 iterations 24
Cbc0038I Pass  18: suminf.    0.23280 (4) obj. 140.28 iterations 22
Cbc0038I Pass  19: suminf.    0.81237 (3) obj. 84.7919 iterations 23
Cbc0038I Pass  20: suminf.    0.45133 (3) obj. 192.419 iterations 8
Cbc0038I Pass  21: suminf.    0.67675 (6) obj. 579.906 iterations 21
Cbc0038I Pass  22: suminf.    0.89960 (5) obj. -94.0115 iterations 29
Cbc0038I Pass  23: suminf.    0.56051 (3) obj. 180.957 iterations 14
Cbc0038I Pass  24: suminf.    0.74317 (3) obj. 37.3469 iterations 14
Cbc0038I Pass  25: suminf.    0.84688 (5) obj. 158.839 iterations 20
Cbc0038I Pass  26: suminf.    0.12352 (3) obj. 695.44 iterations 22
Cbc0038I Pass  27: suminf.    0.54921 (5) obj. 35.9499 iterations 17
Cbc0038I Pass  28: suminf.    0.54457 (4) obj. 782.282 iterations 27
Cbc0038I Pass  29: suminf.    0.53404 (4) obj. 32.8182 iterations 25
Cbc0038I Pass  30: suminf.    0.50976 (4) obj. 311.676 iterations 11
Cbc0038I Rounding solution of 700 is better than previous of 1e+50

Cbc0038I Before mini branch and bound, 9 integers at bound fixed and 0 continuous
Cbc0038I Full problem 125 rows 46 columns, reduced to 116 rows 37 columns
Cbc0038I Mini branch and bound improved solution from 700 to -150 (0.02 seconds)
Cbc0038I Round again with cutoff of -225
Cbc0038I Reduced cost fixing fixed 2 variables on major pass 2
Cbc0038I Pass  30: suminf.    0.98992 (5) obj. -344.44 iterations 23
Cbc0038I Pass  31: suminf.    1.64306 (8) obj. -225 iterations 19
Cbc0038I Pass  32: suminf.    1.01520 (8) obj. -225 iterations 9
Cbc0038I Pass  33: suminf.    0.59837 (5) obj. -225 iterations 29
Cbc0038I Pass  34: suminf.    0.12000 (2) obj. -235 iterations 21
Cbc0038I Pass  35: suminf.    0.56667 (3) obj. -225 iterations 7
Cbc0038I Pass  36: suminf.    0.23800 (3) obj. -225 iterations 4
Cbc0038I Pass  37: suminf.    0.18667 (2) obj. -225 iterations 13
Cbc0038I Pass  38: suminf.    0.60572 (4) obj. -225 iterations 10
Cbc0038I Pass  39: suminf.    0.55246 (4) obj. -225 iterations 3
Cbc0038I Pass  40: suminf.    0.90000 (3) obj. -225 iterations 8
Cbc0038I Pass  41: suminf.    0.90000 (3) obj. -225 iterations 1
Cbc0038I Pass  42: suminf.    0.72410 (4) obj. -225 iterations 10
Cbc0038I Pass  43: suminf.    0.56667 (3) obj. -225 iterations 11
Cbc0038I Pass  44: suminf.    0.25143 (3) obj. -225 iterations 6
Cbc0038I Pass  45: suminf.    0.18667 (2) obj. -225 iterations 16
Cbc0038I Pass  46: suminf.    0.12000 (2) obj. -235 iterations 1
Cbc0038I Pass  47: suminf.    0.56667 (3) obj. -225 iterations 6
Cbc0038I Pass  48: suminf.    0.82724 (7) obj. -225 iterations 31
Cbc0038I Pass  49: suminf.    0.82730 (7) obj. -225 iterations 2
Cbc0038I Pass  50: suminf.    0.59837 (5) obj. -225 iterations 25
Cbc0038I Pass  51: suminf.    0.61314 (6) obj. -273.399 iterations 23
Cbc0038I Pass  52: suminf.    0.63333 (3) obj. -225 iterations 25
Cbc0038I Pass  53: suminf.    0.89613 (4) obj. -225 iterations 7
Cbc0038I Pass  54: suminf.    0.40296 (5) obj. -225 iterations 8
Cbc0038I Pass  55: suminf.    0.52545 (3) obj. -225 iterations 17
Cbc0038I Pass  56: suminf.    0.35917 (4) obj. -247.806 iterations 4
Cbc0038I Pass  57: suminf.    0.23800 (3) obj. -225 iterations 19
Cbc0038I Pass  58: suminf.    0.23800 (3) obj. -225 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass  59: suminf.    0.44904 (3) obj. -225 iterations 12
Cbc0038I No solution found this major pass
Cbc0038I Before mini branch and bound, 12 integers at bound fixed and 0 continuous
Cbc0038I Full problem 125 rows 46 columns, reduced to 95 rows 34 columns
Cbc0038I Mini branch and bound did not improve solution (0.03 seconds)
Cbc0038I After 0.03 seconds - Feasibility pump exiting with objective of -150 - took 0.02 seconds
Cbc0012I Integer solution of -150 found by feasibility pump after 0 iterations and 0 nodes (0.03 seconds)
Cbc0038I Full problem 125 rows 46 columns, reduced to 0 rows 0 columns
Cbc0012I Integer solution of -300 found by DiveCoefficient after 31 iterations and 0 nodes (0.03 seconds)
Cbc0013I At root node, 0 cuts changed objective from -450 to -300 in 3 passes
Cbc0014I Cut generator 0 (Probing) - 37 row cuts average 2.0 elements, 12 column cuts (12 active)  in 0.000 seconds - new frequency is 1
Cbc0014I Cut generator 1 (Gomory) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.000 seconds - new frequency is -100
Cbc0014I Cut generator 2 (Knapsack) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.000 seconds - new frequency is -100
Cbc0014I Cut generator 3 (Clique) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.000 seconds - new frequency is -100
Cbc0014I Cut generator 4 (MixedIntegerRounding2) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.000 seconds - new frequency is -100
Cbc0014I Cut generator 5 (FlowCover) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.000 seconds - new frequency is -100
Cbc0001I Search completed - best objective -300, took 31 iterations and 0 nodes (0.03 seconds)
Cbc0035I Maximum depth 0, 2 variables fixed on reduced cost
Cuts at root node changed objective from -450 to -300
Probing was tried 3 times and created 49 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
Gomory was tried 3 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
Knapsack was tried 3 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
Clique was tried 3 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
MixedIntegerRounding2 was tried 3 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
FlowCover was tried 3 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
TwoMirCuts was tried 1 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
ZeroHalf was tried 1 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)

Result - Optimal solution found

Objective value:                300.00000000
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               31
Time (CPU seconds):             0.03
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.03

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.03   (Wallclock seconds):       0.03

PnL total: 300.00
Assigned rows: 3/6
Bounds:
    lower  upper
v1    1.5    4.0
v2    3.5    7.0
v3    3.5    7.0
v4    3.5    7.0
v5    3.5    7.0
```

This strategy can be [carried to Java](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/617/solving-mip-in-java-with-free-software) without too much fuss.

Comment: the sample data is not randomly generated but actual data. unfortunately, you code did not work correctly for the sample data. I've added the brute force approach but its too slow for data that has more than 3 to 4 variables.

Comment: Exclusion can be down with a pre-processing step.

Answer (score 0):

i have two questions , i think you hope one table have many columns，you need get every columns min and max value?
v1 v2  v3  pnl
7, 8, 12, 100.50,
6, 9, 14, -200.10,
5, 10, 13, 150.25,
8, 11, 15, -510.35,
i run you code ,result is

maxPnL: 250.75
v0 Min: 5, Max: 8
v1 Min: 8, Max: 11
v2 Min: 12, Max: 13
question 1:last result ,max why is 13? ,But isn't it 15.
question 2:maxPnL How is it calculated?

Comment: last var (v3) min/max is 12/13 because only this combination (v0 Min: 5, Max: 8 v1 Min: 8, Max: 11 v2 Min: 12, Max: 13) produces highest maxPnl sum: 250.75.  look at "calculatePnl" code in my question to know how maxPnL is calculated

Answer (score -1):

To determine the minimum and maximum change rates that result in maximum PnL (Profit and Loss).

We can perform an optimization analysis. it involves defining an objective function that represents profit and loss, then identifying the number of coefficients for each variable that maximizes this function.

- **Define your objective function:** Start by defining the function that represents your profit and loss. This function. takes input of the values ​​of the variables that we are optimizing for, and outputs the corresponding profit and loss value.
- **Identify the changes:** Identify the changes what we want to optimize for. These are usually inputs to your value function.
- **Set constraints:** Define any constraints that limit the values ​​of
  each variable.

  - For example, if a variable represents the number of
    units you can produce, then it may be limited by resources or time.
- **Choose an optimization algorithm:** There are many algorithms you can
  use to optimize your objective function, such as gradient descent,
  genetic algorithms, or simulated annealing
- **Perform the optimization:** Run the optimization algorithm for
  the objective function with all of the constraints and wait for the solution.
- **Check the results:** When the optimization is completed, consider the
  result value for each variable and the corresponding Profit and Loss value.

### Example

Suppose you are a farmer who wants to maximize the profit from selling crops. You have two variables to optimize for: the number of acres to plant and the amount of fertilizer to use per acre.

> **Profit = (Price per unit of crop * Yield per acre * Number of acres) - (Cost per unit of fertilizer * Amount of fertilizer per acre * Number of acres)**

- where Price per unit of the crop is the price you can sell the crop for, Yield per acre is the expected yield per acre
- Cost per unit of fertilizer is the cost of buying fertilizer per unit
- Amount of fertilizer per acre is the amount of fertilizer you use per acre.

#### Constraints:

- You have 100 acres of land available to plant.
- You can use at most 500 units of fertilizer.

### Approach

To solve this problem we can use an optimization algorithm like linear programming.

Here are the steps involved:

- Formulate the objective function in terms of linear equations/inequalities.

> **Objective function: Maximize Profit = 10 * Yield * A - 2 * F * A**

where A is the number of acres, F is the amount of fertilizer per acre, and Yield is the yield per acre.

- Implement the linear programming algorithm to find the optimal values of A, F, and Yield that maximize the profit.
- Evaluate the results and check if they make sense. For example, if algorithm suggests that use 200 acres and 400 units of fertilizer, you can check if this is feasible and profitable from a business perspective.

Comment: This seems really generic, and not helpful for the problem at hand.

Comment: Why would you offer an example about a completely different problem?